# Should I encrypt Google and Facebook IDs in the database?

Tags: mongodb, express, passport.js, facebook-login, google-signin

I'm authenticating users via Google and Facebook login in my web app (MERN stack) using passsport.js, first I get the user's ID, I encrypt it using bcryptjs and I store it in the database. The problem is that every time a user signs in, I have to get all the users from the database and compare the ID stored in each one of them with the ID provided by passport.js.
Is there any security risk in storing the IDs directly (no encryption)?

My current code:

```
const users = await User.find({ authProvider: 'facebook' });
const user = users.filter(user => bcrypt.compareSync(profile.id, user.authData.id))[0];
```

I rather have something like this:

`const user = await User.findOne({ 'authData.id': profile.id });`

edit:
Maybe I should find the user based on the profile's email like this:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ authProvider: 'facebook', 'authData.email': profile.emails[0].value });
const isSameID = user ? bcrypt.compareSync(profile.id, user.authData.id) : false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User IDs can be stored without encryption, they are not sensitive at all. You cannot even get any data of a user without his Token in addition. In Facebook, they are even "App Scoped", so they are only valid for a specific App. You could even just share your User ID in public, it really does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user's id is most certainly not as sensitive as a password would be, you need to generate a random salt *once* and store it in the database. Then use that common salt to hash the user ids that you store, as well as hashing the user id that you are checking. The comparison then is a simple binary comparison, and the database can be indexed over those blobs.

Something like:

```
const salt = ...; // retrieved from db
const profile_hash = bcrypt.hashSync(profile.id, salt);
const user = await User.findOne({ 'authData.id': profile_hash });
```

Comment: That doesn't work because bcrypt generates a different hash every time you use it, even if the input and salt are the same, maybe I should use something different to encrypt the IDs, maybe I shouldn't encrypt them at all (I don't know how sensitive they are, what could someone really do with them?), or maybe I could authenticate users based on their email instead, I don't know.